# How to identify changes to a list of customers over time

Tags: t-sql

I have a cohort of customers that changes fairly regularly. Each time the cohort changes, a complete dump of the new customers is appended to the table and given a new List_Name. Alpha, Beta, Gamma, etc. Each list generally add some customers, removes some customers, and keeps some customers. I'm trying to create a simple waterfall chart to show the changes from list to list. Typically I would just FULL OUTER JOIN Alpha<->Beta, then FULL OUTER JOIN Beta<->Gamma, etc etc to get the customers that are staying, leaving, and being added. But the List_Versions are growing quite a bit and I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this calc instead of having to edit it every time a new list is appended. I am not able to change this process since it supports legacy systems and is controlled by another department. Thoughts?

EDIT: Sql Server 2016 SP2.

```
CREATE TABLE #customers(cust_id int, list_name varchar(10), create_dt date)
INSERT INTO #customers values (1,'Alpha','2019-01-01')
    ,(2,'Alpha','2019-01-01')
    ,(3,'Alpha','2019-01-01')
    ,(4,'Alpha','2019-01-01')
    ,(5,'Alpha','2019-01-01')
    ,(2,'Beta','2019-03-01')
    ,(3,'Beta','2019-03-01')
    ,(4,'Beta','2019-03-01')
    ,(5,'Beta','2019-03-01')
    ,(6,'Beta','2019-03-01')
    ,(7,'Beta','2019-03-01')
    ,(1,'Gamma','2019-05-05')
    ,(6,'Gamma','2019-05-05')
    ,(7,'Gamma','2019-05-05')
    ,(9,'Gamma','2019-05-05')

--Desired Output (long way that needs to be edited every time there is a new list)
SELECT List_Name, 'Starting' Descrip, count(*) Custs FROM #customers WHERE list_name = 'alpha' group by list_name
UNION ALL
SELECT List_Name, 'Add', count(*) FROM #customers a WHERE list_name = 'Beta' AND not exists(SELECT * FROM #customers x WHERE List_Name = 'Alpha' AND a.cust_id = x.cust_id) GROUP BY List_Name
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beta', 'Remove', -count(*) FROM #customers a WHERE list_name = 'Alpha' AND not exists(SELECT * FROM #customers x WHERE List_Name = 'Beta' AND a.cust_id = x.cust_id) GROUP BY List_Name
UNION ALL
SELECT List_Name, 'Add', count(*) FROM #customers a WHERE list_name = 'Gamma' AND not exists(SELECT * FROM #customers x WHERE List_Name = 'Beta' AND a.cust_id = x.cust_id) GROUP BY List_Name
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gamma', 'Remove', -count(*) FROM #customers a WHERE list_name = 'Beta' AND not exists(SELECT * FROM #customers x WHERE List_Name = 'Gamma' AND a.cust_id = x.cust_id) GROUP BY List_Name
```

Comment: You could perhaps add a process? You could do "date effecting" using the MERGE command in SQL Server, into a new table that does not affect the current process. The concept is that new records (not appearing in the target) are added to the table, and old records (no longer appearing in the source) are outdated in the table. You end up with a table that basically just records the difference between intervals.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 SP2

Comment: Can you give us a table definition and some sample data?

Comment: Do you need to keep a history of the changes to each customer? If a customer is removed from the cohort, is it just not included in data being appended to the table?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to create a waterfall chart. Started with 1000 customers in List Alpha. Then when list Beta was appended, it contains 150 new customers that were not in Alpha (+150) and is missing 200 customers that were in Alpha (-200). Management wants to see the changes in the list over time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_chart

Comment: How do you know what order the list names go in?

Comment: Assume there is a date field on when the list was loaded. All IDs in a given list have the same date. I'll update the sample code now...

Comment: For each new “list” you need to identify the list that preceeded it. The way your data is laid out makes this really tedious. I would suggest getting rid of the `varchar` list name in favor of strictly consecutive numbers. You could use these numbers as foreign keys and store a name and date for each import in another table, thus normalizing your data. If you guarantee that the IDs are consecutive, you can go from one import to the one before by just -1ing it. Or perhaps more robustly, establish some other way of doing this, like storing the preceeding ID.

Comment: As previously stated, this data is owned by IT and they will not make changes. There is a create date that lets me know the order.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the list names, you can create a temp table to generate ids, and then use the ids as join conditions for the aggregations. This will allow you to a list to the previous list without relying on knowing the names and the order they were generated.

```
CREATE TABLE #customers(cust_id int, list_name varchar(10), list_date date)
INSERT INTO #customers
(
    cust_id
    ,list_name
    ,list_date
)
values (1,'Alpha', '01-01-2019')
    ,(2,'Alpha', '01-01-2019')
    ,(3,'Alpha', '01-01-2019')
    ,(4,'Alpha', '01-01-2019')
    ,(5,'Alpha', '01-01-2019')
    ,(2,'Beta', '02-01-2019')
    ,(3,'Beta', '02-01-2019')
    ,(4,'Beta', '02-01-2019')
    ,(5,'Beta', '02-01-2019')
    ,(6,'Beta', '02-01-2019')
    ,(7,'Beta', '02-01-2019')
    ,(1,'Gamma', '03-01-2019')
    ,(6,'Gamma', '03-01-2019')
    ,(7,'Gamma', '03-01-2019')
    ,(9,'Gamma', '03-01-2019')


CREATE TABLE #lists
(
    list_id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,list_name varchar(10)
    ,Starting INT
    ,Added INT
    ,Removed INT
    ,list_date date
)

INSERT INTO #lists
(
    list_name
    ,Starting
    ,Added
    ,Removed
    ,list_date
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.list_name 
    ,Starting = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #customers b WHERE b.list_name = a.list_name)
    ,Added = 0
    ,Removed = 0
    ,a.list_date
FROM #customers a
ORDER BY a.list_date ASC
```

Now use this temp table to create another temp table with customer ids and list ids. I do this so I don't have to keep writing joins to link list names and list ids.

```
SELECT c.cust_id
      ,l.list_id
INTO #ListCus
FROM #customers c
INNER JOIN #lists l ON l.list_name = c.list_name
```

Next you can calculate the Added and Removed numbers.

```
UPDATE l 
SET l.Added = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ListCus c1 WHERE c1.list_id = l.list_id AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #ListCus x WHERE x.list_id = l.list_id-1 AND c1.cust_id = x.cust_id))
    ,l.Removed = (SELECT -COUNT(*) FROM #ListCus c1 WHERE c1.list_id = l.list_id-1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #ListCus x WHERE x.list_id = l.list_id AND c1.cust_id = x.cust_id)) 
FROM #lists l
WHERE l.list_id > 1 --the first list won't have Added or Removed records
```

Finally we format the data by unpivoting and filtering out unneeded Descrips.

```
;WITH unpivoted AS
(
    SELECT
        u.list_id
        ,u.Descrip
        ,u.custs
    FROM #lists l 
    UNPIVOT
    (
        custs 
        FOR Descrip IN (Starting, Added, Removed)
    )u
)
,SubResults AS
(
    SELECT u.list_id
          ,u.Descrip
          ,u.custs
    FROM unpivoted u 
    WHERE u.list_id = 1
        AND u.Descrip = 'Starting'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT u.list_id
          ,u.Descrip
          ,u.custs
    FROM unpivoted u 
    WHERE u.list_id <> 1
        AND u.Descrip <> 'Starting'
)
SELECT 
    l.list_name
    ,s.Descrip
    ,s.custs
FROM SubResults s
INNER JOIN #lists l ON l.list_id = s.list_id
ORDER BY s.list_id ASC, s.Descrip
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you can store your “Lists” in a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) and do the following. It’s not sexy, but it will give you the output below. You can obviously `*-1` as you see fit.

```
WITH lists (ListName, ListDate, PreceedingDate)
AS
(
    select distinct list_name, create_dt, PreceedingDate
    from #customers C1
        outer apply (select top 1 PreceedingDate = C3.create_dt
                     from #customers C3
                     where C3.create_dt < C1.create_dt
                     order by C3.create_dt desc) C3
)
select ListID = coalesce(lists.ListDate, CTE2.ListDate)
    , ListName = max(lists.ListName)
    , Added = SUM(IIF(C2.cust_id is null, 1, 0))
    , Removed = SUM(IIF(C1.cust_id is null and C2.cust_id is not null, 1, 0))
    , Remained = SUM(IIF(C2.cust_id = C1.cust_id, 1, 0))
from lists
    inner join #customers C1 on C1.create_dt = lists.ListDate
    full outer join #customers C2 on C1.cust_id = C2.cust_id
                                    and C2.create_dt = lists.PreceedingDate
    --since for removed customers the current List will be NULL
    --we join it back on, which leads to all those COALESCEs
    left join lists CTE2 on CTE2.PreceedingDate = C2.create_dt
where coalesce(lists.ListDate, CTE2.ListDate) is not null
group by coalesce(lists.ListDate, CTE2.ListDate)
```

Result:

```
ListID     | ListName | Added | Removed | Remained
-----------|----------|-------|---------|---------
2019-01-01 | Alpha    | 5     | 0       | 0
2019-03-01 | Beta     | 2     | 1       | 4
2019-05-05 | Gamma    | 2     | 4       | 2
```